# Promises.all not fired after looping through multiple ajax requests

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, es6-promise

I'm importing a json file and loop through the object. 
Each object has an array with eventIDs, which I loop through as well. 
In this forEach I push a wrapper function that returns a Promise into an array `promises`

After looping through all objects I perform a `promise.all()` on the `promises` array. But strangely anything I do after this loop is not executed.

```
const fs = require('fs')
const promisify = require('util').promisify
const rp = require('request-promise')
const readFile = promisify(fs.readFile)
const filePath = 'json/results.json'

let promises = []

function init() {
  readFile(filePath, 'utf8')
  .then(file => {
    const json = JSON.parse(file)

    for (const country of json) {
      if (country.eventIDs.length === 0) return

      country.eventIDs.forEach(id => promises.push(getEventData(country, id)))
    }

// nothing here is executed,  
    console.log('this is not fired')

    Promise.all(promises)
           .then(results => writeFile(results))
           .catch( err => console.log(err))
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err))
}

getEventData = (country, id) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

  setTimeout(() => {
    rp(url)
    .then((results) => {      
      resolve ({
        ...results
      })
    })
    .catch((err) => reject(`getEventData Error:\n ${err}`))
  }, 2000)
})

writeFile = (results) => {
  const json = JSON.stringify(results)
  // const date = new Date()
  // const filename = `${date.getTime()}-all-event-ids.json`
  const filename = `results-allevents.json`
  fs.writeFile(`json/${filename}`, json, 'utf8', () => console.log(`Succesfully written: ${filename}`))
}

init()
```

Comment: promises is an Array of `Promise`. Replace `promises.push(getEventData(country, id).then(res => res))` with: `promises.push(getEventData(country, id))`. Otherwise, you're just not pushing a promise and the block inside the .then is async. Beware though: `results` will be an **array** of `res`. Also, you should handle the `.catch` Promise.all event. Also, no need to `return` inside the `setTimeout` callback. Moreover, where is `rp` declared?... Also, `promises` is **not** declared, should be `let promises = []`

Comment: sorry I didn't post the complete code, let me add

Comment: Also, ensure that the `init` function is called.

Comment: The edit you provided is **much** different from the original post. Is it still logging **nothing**? Also, what is this line supposed to do? `if (country.eventIDs.length === 0) return`. This will block the whole execution, do you want to skip the item?

Comment: sorry I only posted what I thought was essential to my question. Yes it still doesn't log anything. Anything after the 'for' loop is not executed

Comment: Please provide `console.log(json)` (after JSON.parse). Add as many info as possibles. It's either blocked by the return statement, either not joining the for at all since `json` can be null or undefined.

Comment: ah removing `if (country.eventIDs.length === 0) return` did the job! I'm not sure I understand why though. If you could give this in a reply below, I'll mark that as answer. thanks!

Comment: Done. Next time, please, provide **as many informations as possible**. There were many issues in the original code and please, if you edit the code, **keep it as it originally was**, do not alter it, otherwise it becomes hard to keep track of what was originally your intention and what you fixed by reading comments ;). Read this for further informations: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It's just that the `return` keyword just stop the execution of the init() function. If you want to skip to the next item when `country.eventIDs.length === 0` then you should use the keyword `continue`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the investigation, the line:

`if (country.eventIDs.length === 0) return`

was the main issue (and many others solved through comments).

The issue, to explain that, is that the `return` is not skipping the looped item (as perhaps expected), but rather returning `void` in the `then` callback, so skipping further executions of that block.

In order to "skip" the item if that condition is true, just do this instead

```
    for (const country of json) {
      if (country.eventIDs.length > 0) { 
          country.eventIDs.forEach(id => promises.push(getEventData(country, id))) 
      }
    }
```

Comment: thanks! I wasn't even aware of a `void` value in js. Learning every day. 

In the end I replaced `return` with `continue`, which would skip the false conditions.

Comment: @flowen technically you're just returning nothing, which equals to returning `void 0`, which equals to `undefined` (which is **not** null). Play with it if you want to test more: http://jsfiddle.net/briosheje/v9bpzegm/ . In a nutshell, keep in mind that the callback you're using (the `file =>` lambda) is an **anonymous function**, whose return type can be of any type. In your case, you were explicitely telling that in that case the execution of that function should've been stopped (that's what return does).

Answer (score 0):

better is to capture each result from each promise. Because if you want array of responses of the .All . If one of those promises reject you will get no results.

```
const results = [];

country.eventIDs.forEach(id => promises.push(getEventData(country, id)
.then(res =>  results.push(res));

Promise.all(promises).then(()=> writeFile(results))
```

[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ngcgrb)

Comment: Promise.all will be called immediately, since `promises` will not be an array of promises (hence non-promise values are ignored), but an array of fulfilled objects.

Comment: just saying promises.all will resolve until the first rejected promise.  Then it won't return all previous result from the resolved promises.